# How to set QuestDB configuration defaults when using in Docker?

Tags: docker, questdb

I spin QuestDB in docker container as suggested in the docs

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 \
 -p 9009:9009 \
 -p 8812:8812 \
 -p 9003:9003 \
 questdb/questdb
```

How can I override number of threads in the worker pool default configuration for the container from 2 to 8?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a property to override from [configuration list](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/configuration/) there is a way to specify it as environment variable for the container with `QDB_` prefix and `_` instead of `.` in the variable name. In case of shared worker count it should be

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 \
 -p 9009:9009 \
 -p 8812:8812 \
 -p 9003:9003 \
 -e QDB_SHARED_WORKER_COUNT=8 \
 questdb/questdb
```